# Possible bug with DirectoryIterator

Tags: c++, iterator, directory, mingw, poco-libraries

Working with `DirectoryIterator` example, from Poco documentation, I have some issues with it.

This is the source code:

```
#include "Poco/DirectoryIterator.h"
#include <iostream>

using Poco::DirectoryIterator;
using Poco::Path;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::string cwd(Path::current());

    DirectoryIterator it(cwd);
    DirectoryIterator end;

    while (it != end) {
        std::cout << it.name();
        if (it->isFile())
            std::cout << it->getSize();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        Path p(it.path());
        ++it;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am using Mingw, with gcc 8.2, under Msys2 and Windows 7 (tested with Windows 10 too). Using Eclipse CDT as IDE.

When compiling in Debug mode, and run the binary, the exception "Path not found" is thrown.

When compiling in Release mode, and run the binary, it works, but the iterator "it" doesn't evolve.

It always shows "**a.txt**"

I am trying the example with this directory tree:

```
/test//a.txt
/test//b.txt
/test//test2
/test/test2/c.txt
/test/test2/d.txt
```

I have tested the same example in linux, and everything is working ok.

Why does it work in Linux, but not in Windows?

Any clue?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling your program, I get the next message: *"`Compiling POCO on Windows without #define POCO_WIN32_UTF8 is deprecated`"*

You need to compile with `#define POCO_WIN32_UTF8.`

```
#define POCO_WIN32_UTF8
#include "Poco/DirectoryIterator.h"
```